# Identification singular measures in one-point compactification

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $X_\infty = X \cup \{ \infty \}$ its one-point compactification. We identify $C(X_\infty) = C_0(X) \oplus \mathbb{R}$ by mapping $g \in C(X_\infty)$ to $(g|_X - g(\infty), g(\infty))$. By duality we can then identify $(C_0(X) \oplus \mathbb{R})' = C(X_\infty)'$ isometrically isomorphic as Banach spaces.
Since the left-hand side is a finite direct sum of Banach spaces we get the identifications
$C_0(X)' \oplus \mathbb{R} = C_0(X)' \oplus \mathbb{R}' = (C_0(X) \oplus \mathbb{R})' = C(X_\infty)'$. From the Riesz representation theorem, we then get

$$M(X) \oplus \mathbb{R} = M(X_\infty)$$

where $M(Y)$ is the space of signed Radon measures on a locally compact space $Y$.

On the other hand, we can also look at the Lebesgue decomposition for measures $\nu \in M(X_\infty)$ w.r.t. $\delta_\infty$ which gives $\nu = \nu_s + \nu_{ac} = \nu_s + c \delta_\infty$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$, where $\nu_s \in Rca(X_\infty)$ is the singular part $\nu_s \perp \delta_\infty$ and $\nu_{ac} = c \delta_\infty$ the absolutely continuous part. Since $\lVert \nu \rVert = \lVert \nu_s \rVert + \lVert \nu_{ac} \rVert$ we get a (topological) direct sum decomposition

$$M(X_\infty) = M(X_\infty)_s \oplus \mathbb{R}.$$

I would like to know whether these two identifications of $M(X_\infty)$ are in fact identical, i.e. that these two identifications of $M(X)$ imply an identification $M(X_\infty)_s = M(X)$ (and that of the two one-dimensional subspaces $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Yes, note that $\delta_\infty$ is zero on $C_0(X)$ and that a measure singular wrt $\delta_\infty$ must be supported outside of $\infty$, hence must be $0$ on the $\Bbb R$ factor.  The decomposition $(\nu_s,c\delta_\infty)$ thus respects the decomposition $C_0(X)\oplus\Bbb R$.

Comment: @s.harp Hmm, a measure singular wrt $\delta_\infty$ need not be supported outside of $\infty$: Take for instance $X = (0, 1]$ so that $X \cup \{ \infty \}$ is then $[0, 1]$ (with its usual topology) and $0$ playing the role of the point at infinity. Then the Lebesgue measure $m$ on $[0,1]$ is singular w.r.t. $\delta_0$ but the support of $m$ is all of $[0, 1]$ - it is not outside of $0$. (Note also that the support of a measure is always a closed set.)

Comment: You are right of course, I had a few wrong thoughts. The decomposition of $M(X)$ does not actually respect the decomposition of $C(X)$. Because $(0,c)\in C_0(X)\oplus\Bbb R$ corresponds to the constant function $c$ you have that $\nu_s((0,c)) = c\nu_s(X_\infty)$, which need not be zero. The decomposition of $M(X_\infty)\cong M(X)\oplus \Bbb R$ that respects the decomposition of $C(X_\infty)\cong C_0(X)\oplus \Bbb R$ should be given by $(\nu,c)[f] = \nu(f)+c\,f(\infty) - \nu(X)f(\infty)$. Here you have that $(0,c)(C_0(X))=0$ and $(\nu ,0 ) (\Bbb R) =0$.

Comment: In other words $\nu\in M(X_\infty)$ should be decomposed to $\nu=[\nu-\nu(X_\infty)\delta_\infty] \oplus \nu(X_\infty)\delta_\infty$.

Comment: @s.harp Ok, so in other words, the two decompositions as mentioned in the question are different, namely 1. the decomposition $M(X_\infty) = M(X) \oplus \mathbb{R}$ coming from the duality of $C_0(X) \oplus \mathbb{R}$ and 2. the decomposition $M(X_\infty) = M(X_\infty)_s \oplus \mathbb{R}$ coming from the Lebesgue decomposition wrt $\delta_\infty$. In your comment, you describe the decomposition 1. in other terms.

Comment: Yes, that is right, they differ.

Comment: @s.harp The extension mapping $M(X) \to M(X_\infty)$, $\mu \mapsto \hat{\mu}$, $\hat{\mu}(B\cup E) = \mu(B)$ for $B\in\mathcal{B}(X)$ and $E=\emptyset$ or $E=\{\infty\}$ embedds $M(X)$ as a linear subspace into $M(X_\infty)$ and provides a decomposition $M(X_\infty)=M(X)\oplus\mathbb{R}$, $\nu=\hat{\nu|_X}+\nu\{\infty\}\delta_\infty$. But this is the same as the Lebesgue decomposition $\nu=\nu_s+c\delta_\infty$: for the splitting $X_\infty=X\cup\{\infty\}$ we have $c \delta_\infty = \nu\{\infty\}\delta_\infty=0$ on $X$ and $\hat{\nu|_X}=0$ on $\{\infty\}$, so that $\hat{\nu|_X} = \nu_s$.